# Laravel 5. Как реализовать отношение многие ко многим?

Tags: база-данных, laravel, orm

В БД имеются 3 таблицы Книги, категории книг и таблица которая связывает их между собой.
Как с помощью Eloquent: Relationships связать их ?
[image: Структура БД]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Связь [многие ко многим](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through):

```
Book::categories(): 
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Category', 'books2category');
    // 'book_id', 'category_id' можно не указывать т.к. названия соответствуют моделям

Category::books(): 
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Book', 'books2category');
    // 'category_id', 'book_id' тоже можно не указывать
```